# vertical expand div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two DIV

one on the right the the other on the left side

I'm looking for a code that give me link and by clicking on this link both divs will expand to 100% (mean that one of them will slide down) and by click again they will return back to be side by  side

I tried this:

```
<style>
#container {
   width:100%;
   height:500px;

}
#left {

    width:45%;
    height:500px;
    float: left;
}
#right {

    width:45%;
    height:500px;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>  


<div id="container">
      <div id="left">
       LEFT
    </div>

      <div id="right">
        RIGHT 
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#container').click(function(){
        if (parseInt($('div#right').css('right'),10) < 0) {
                 // Bring right-column back onto display
                  $('div#right').animate({
                      right:'0%'
                  }, 1000);

                  $('div#left').animate({
                    width:'45%'
                  }, 600);
                } else {

        // Animate column off display.
                  $('div#right').animate({
                      right:'-45%'
                  }, 600);

                  $('div#left').animate({
                    width:'100%'
                  }, 1000);
        }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery's `toggle` function? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery toggle, for your puspose.

Have a look at this [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyXvv/)